# Displaying % symbol in C++ and Ncurses

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

does anyone know how to display the percentage `%` character in an ncurses-based C++ / C=based program?

I have tried using `\x25` and `%`, but they do not work.

Comment: Escape it `printf("some %%\n");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to escape the `%` with an extra `%`:

```
%%
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked (although I am not certain why \x25 did not).

Answer (score 4):

You don't provide an example of how you're trying to use it, but the normal answer would be to double up the % or escape it...

```
"%%"
```

or

```
"\%"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra % like that

```
 "%%"
```